# At what scale of data is the ROI of partitioning the most valuable?

Tags: sql, database-design, data-warehouse, database-partitioning

So I'm looking into data warehousing and partitioning and am very curious at to what scale makes the most sense for partitioning a data on a key (for instance, `SaleDate`).

Tutorials often mention that you're trying to break it down into logical chunks so as to make updating the data less likely to cause service disruptions.

So let's say I'm a medium scale company working in a given US state. I do a lot of work in relation to `SaleDate`, often tens of thousands of transactions a day (with requisite transaction details, 4-50 each?), and have about 5 years of data. I would like to query and build trend information off of that; for instance:

- On a yearly basis to know what items are becoming less popular over time.
- On a monthly basis to see what items get popular at a certain time of year (ice in summer)
- On a weekly basis to see how well my individual stores are doing
- On a daily basis to observe theft trends or something

Now my business unit also wants to query that data, but I'd like to be able to keep it responsive.

How do I know that it would be best to partition on Year, Month, Week, Day, etc for this data set? Is it just whatever I actually observe as providing the best response time by testing out each scenario? Or is there some kind of scale that I can use to understand where my partitions would be the most efficient?

Edit: I, personally, am using Sql Server 2012. But I'm curious as to how others view this question in relation to the core concept rather than the implementation (Unless this isn't one of those cases where you can do so).

Answer (score 3):

Things to consider:

1. What type of database are you using? Really important, different strategies for Oracle vs SQLServer vs IBM, etc.
2. Sample queries and run times. Partitions usage depends on the conditions in your where clause, what are you filtering on?
3. Does it make sense to create/use aggregate tables? Seems like a monthly aggregate would save you some time.
4. Partitions usage depends on the conditions in your where clause, what are you filtering on?

Lots of options based on the hardware and storage options available to you, need more details to make a more specific recommendation.

Comment: "Sample queries and run times" Agreed, the size of your partition should be no smaller than necessary to obtain reasonable query performance, or else you're making too many partitions and creating more complexity than necessary.  If partitioning on year yields query times which are reasonable, then don't partition any smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Ms-SQL 2012 database with 7 million records a day, with an ambition to grow the database to 6 years of data for trend analyses.

The partitions are based on the YearWeek column, expressed as an integer (after 201453 comes 201501). So each partition holds one week of transaction data. 
This makes for a maximum of 320 partitions, which is well chosen below the maximum of 1000 partitions within a scheme. The maximum size for one partition in one table is now approx. 10 Gb, which makes it much easier to handle than the 3Tb size of the total.

A new file in the partition scheme is used for each new year. The 500Gb datafiles are suitable for backup and deletion.

When calculating data for one month the 4 processors are working in parallel to handle one partition each.